# How do you exclude streets from Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

How do you exclude streets from coming up when using the Google Places API?  I want only cities and states to show if a user types in a location in the input field

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add `types` to your Place Autocomplete requests.

Concretely, `types=(regions)` will limit Autocomplete predictions to cities, states, and a few more. See [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) in the API documentation for more details.